# How to factorize events between 2 C# classes since events can only be fired in same class it's defined?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have for class A and class B:

```
public event CustomEvent1 event1
public event CustomEvent2 event2
```

How can I create a class C which A & B would inherit the events since events can only be fired in same class it's defined ?

Comment: Just have a `RaiseEvent` function that can be called from the derived classes.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you should define in class C a method like

```
protected void OnEventName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomEventC evt = EventC;
    if (evt != null)
        evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Since it is a protected method, it will be visible from classes A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Make an `OnCustomEvent` method in the `C` class that calls the event. Then you can call the method from the `A` and `B` classes.

You can look in the framework in any webform or winform control that uses events for an example of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Calling C# events from outside the owning class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107972/calling-c-events-from-outside-the-owning-class)