# C#: What's the intended replacement for firing events from outside an object?

Tags: c#

C# has gone to [great lengths to ensure that you cannot "fire" an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107972/calling-c-sharp-events-from-outside-the-owning-class), e.g.:

```
form.FormClosed(this, new FormClosedEventArgs(CloseReason.UserClosing));

button.Click(this, new EventArgs());

customer.AddressChanged(this, new EventArgs());
```

don't compile because you cannot fire an event this way.

This seems to have been a conscious decision on the part of the language designers. They seem to be intentionally trying to prevent "bad behavior".

i am trying to find the *intended* replacement.

Practical Example:

```
void ShowPopup(Form form)
{
   ToolStripDropDown toolDrop = new ToolStripDropDown();
   ToolStripControlHost toolHost = new ToolStripControlHost(form);
   toolHost.Margin = new Padding(0);
   toolDrop.Padding = new Padding(0);
   toolDrop.Items.Add(toolHost);

   toolDrop.Closed += toolDrop_Closed;
   toolDrop.Show(screenLocation);
}

void toolDrop_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
{
   //The form's FormClosed event doesn't fire when shown as a popup
   //Fire the event manually
   form.FormClosed(this, new FormClosedEventArgs(CloseReason.UserClosing));
}
```

If i'm not *supposed* to fire events from outside the object - what is the technique *intended* to replace it?

---

If there is no intended replacement for firing events, is there any article, book, or Channel 9 video that explains how i *should* handle this situation?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with. NET, per se; but is instead a function of the accessibility of members of an object.

Answer (score 4):

An event inside a class has often a public method used by class clients to invoke the event from outside of the class:

```
public class Foo {
  public event FooDelegate FooEvent;

  public void RaiseFoo() {
     if ( FooEvent != null ) FooEvent();
  }      
}
```

If an event is *missing* such public "trigger", it usually means that for some reason you should not be able to raise the event from outside.

In your example, the event can of course be raised with

```
form.Close();
```

with, apart from other things, also raises the event.

Comment: The problem comes from classes that don't have a public method that can be used to throw a desired event.

Comment: It just means the class raises events internally and you probably should not do it from outside. Sure, just like with private methods, you can do this by reflection but it's against someone's intentions. Take an event coming from a Win32 message. It's raised internally from within a message loop as a result of message caught by the loop. What could be the reason to raise such event by yourself if the real cause of the event (the message) didn't happen?